# HDP 2.6.5 : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.DefaultSource

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using HDP 2.6.5 and when i want to save my data (get on a json file) to a mongoDB database i have this problem.

I'm using the sandbox.

My code :

```
#HDFS-Mongo Used to write the json file from HDFS to Mongo DB

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

my_spark = SparkSession \
         .builder \
         .appName("testdb") \
         .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/testdb.test1") \
         .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/testdb.test1") \
         .getOrCreate()


df = my_spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/output2.json")

df.count()

df.printSchema()

df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append").option("database","testdb").option("collection", "test1").save()
```

The errors :

> `Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                            File "hdfs_mongo.py", line 19, in <module>                                                                                                    df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append").option("database","testdb").option("collection", "test1").save()    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 738, in save                                                    self._jwrite.save()                                                                                                                       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__                                                    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)                                                                                   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco                                                         return f(*a, **kw)                                                                                                                        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value                                                 format(target_id, ".", name), value)                                                                                                    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o44.save.                                                                      : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:                                                                                                         Failed to find data source: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource. Please find packages at                                                    http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html                                                                                                   at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:443)                            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:670)                                            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:720)                                          at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.lookupV2Provider(DataFrameWriter.scala:852)                                                         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:256)                                                             at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:247)                                                                     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                                                              at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)                                                            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)                                                                                         at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)                                                                             at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)                                                                       at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)                                                                                                    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)                                                                     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)                                                                                   at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)                                                             at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.DefaultSource                                                      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)                                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)                                                                                    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:656)                                 at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)                                                                                                     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:656)                                 at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)                                                                                                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:656)                                            ... 16 more`

I already try to uninstall python and install again (python3.6), i use this code and run it but it don't works :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myApp") \
.config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/sample1.zips") \
.config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/sample1.zips") \
.config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.2') \
.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
df.printSchema()
```

Comment: The HDP sandbox has not been updated in years, it's not longer supported, and doesn't run mongodb so connecting to 127.0.0.1 would not work, anyway. Have you considered installing later version of Spark on your own machine (`pip install pyspark`), and running mongodb not in a VM?

Comment: In any case, using `spark.jars.packages`is correct, so what was the error you got when you did use that, and what command did you use to run the code?